# how to stop angular router events from printing on console

Tags: angular, router, console.log

I am making an angular app and am using the `{RouterModule} from @angular/router`.

I use the console.log to debug my Application, but since I started using the router module, it has started *spamming* the console with router events, which makes it hard to see my actual logs.

How can I stop  angular router events from printing on console?

Edit 1: Picture of logs

[image: Picture of logs]

Comment: What kind of routing events are showing in console?

Comment: I have shared a screenshot of logs in the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the attached screenshot you should need to **Enable production mode** for your angular application to avoid these logs
(As angular application run in development mode by default).

Just put this piece code in your **main.ts file** before calling bootstrapping of your application -

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';

enableProdMode();
bootstrap(....);
```

## update

Search `enableTracing` keyword in your routing file, either remove it or set it to false.

```
{ enableTracing: false }
```

For more info , refer here -

- https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#forroot

Comment: have you restart your application from console? it should work.

Comment: I did. And I ran it in both chrome and Firefox to be sure it's not a browser thing. I'm using `ng serv` to run the application, in case that helps. The logs seem to come from some **platform-browser.js**

Comment: It's not working either. It works on projects on stackblitz, but its not working on my project, and its not working on another project that I am using routing in. But is seems like a logical answer. Let me try making a new  project and try it there.

Comment: Sure, But there in your code must have added console for output, verify it once again. Good luck

Comment: It's working in the new project, There must be some problem with my current project. I'll look for that.

Comment: Found the error, there was another definition of a router with enableTracing true.

Answer (score 8):

In your Module search for :

```
 imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
            // this Debug options:
            { enableTracing: false }
        )
    ]
```

`enableTracing` should be false

Comment: oh you updated your answer.. May not..only specify where he can search for the debug option